# Pandas groupby collapse 1st rows of group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a system that lets me export data in a table of this format:
​

```
data = {'record_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
        'name':['AA',"","","",'BB',"",'CC',"",""],
        'data':["",'foo1','foo2','foo3',"",'foo4',"",'foo5','foo6']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
   record_id name  data
0          1   AA      
1          1       foo1
2          1       foo2
3          1       foo3
4          2   BB      
5          2       foo4
6          3   CC      
7          3       foo5
8          3       foo6
```

where there are many columns like 'data' and they can have any values that don't necessarily follow a pattern. I need to get the data into this format:

```
data_out = {'name':['AA','AA','AA','BB','CC','CC'],'data':['foo1','foo2','foo3','foo4','foo5','foo6']}
df_out = pd.DataFrame(data_out)
print(df_out)
  name  data
0   AA  foo1
1   AA  foo2
2   AA  foo3
3   BB  foo4
4   CC  foo5
5   CC  foo6
```

I've tried reading the documentation on `gropuby` and searching similar questions, but I can't find a way to collapse just the 1st 2 rows of each group into 1 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)-

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
df['name'] = df['name'].ffill()
df = df.dropna(subset=['data'])
```

**Output**

```
   record_id name  data
1          1   AA  foo1
2          1   AA  foo2
3          1   AA  foo3
5          2   BB  foo4
7          3   CC  foo5
8          3   CC  foo6
```

You can optionally drop the `record_id` column with a `.drop()` at the end to get the desired output `df_out`

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan, regex=True)
df['data'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df['name'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset =['data'])
```

---

```
df = df.iloc[1: , :]
```

[image]